# jQuery 'viewstate'-like behavior

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a website in jquery mobile. It is a SOA application and on 'pageshow' event I call the web services get the data and populate labels and dropdown lists with it. However, say for instance, when a user clicks back and the app takes him back to dashboard, the ajax call is made again and the labels are unnecessarily populated again. What I want to ask is, can I prevent this behaviour of populating the same labels with the same data over and over again? Does jquery mobile have this 'viewstate' behavior built in?

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: check for any Cache feature..

Comment: I think you misunderstand vewstate it doesn't provide the behavior you describe, it doesn't prevent the data being fetched from the server again, it simply "remembers" the state of the controls (e.g. the selected item in a select list) on the page between post backs

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML5's localStorage / sessionStorage API to actually persist data between callbacks.

Personally I think that if you'd use JQM's page idiom (having only data-role=page and not loading any new ajax pages), you wouldn't have this problem at all (but rather the opposite, how to reset all fields).